# II7 prompt for username/password for virtual directory

Tags: iis, iis-7

I have a virtual directory setup on my server. The main website is public on port 80 but I have a /subfolder virtual directory that I want to ask for a username and password (not a ASP page, standard username password prompt).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the permissions on each directory separately, so you can leave the main site open to everyone (allow anonymous access), but then restrict the subdirectory (turn off anonymous access and turn on something else, such as basic authentication--just be aware of the security implications if you use basic authentication over HTTP instead of HTTPS).  Select the directory and then click on the Authentication option to change these settings.

See also http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733010%28WS.10%29.aspx for more info on the pros and cons of various authentication options and the things you should consider.